# How to get or set Selected index of the Radio Button List using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, javascript-framework

How I can radio button checked using index..
Below is my asp.net C# code for radion button list...

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rdlCategory" CssClass="clsradio" AppendDataBoundItems="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" >
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

and Bind it using  C# dynamically..
and Html looks like

```
<span class="clsradio" id="ctl00_cphTop_rdlCategory"><input type="radio" value="8" name="ctl00$cphTop$rdlCategory" id="ctl00_cphTop_rdlCategory_0"> 
    <label for="ctl00_cphTop_rdlCategory_0">category1</label>
    <input type="radio" value="11" name="ctl00$cphTop$rdlCategory" id="ctl00_cphTop_rdlCategory_1">
    <label for="ctl00_cphTop_rdlCategory_1">category2</label>
    <input type="radio" value="22" name="ctl00$cphTop$rdlCategory" id="ctl00_cphTop_rdlCategory_2">
    <label for="ctl00_cphTop_rdlCategory_2">category3</label>
    <input type="radio" value="33" name="ctl00$cphTop$rdlCategory" id="ctl00_cphTop_rdlCategory_3">
    <label for="ctl00_cphTop_rdlCategory_3">category4</label>
    <input type="radio" value="34" name="ctl00$cphTop$rdlCategory" id="ctl00_cphTop_rdlCategory_4">
    <label for="ctl00_cphTop_rdlCategory_4">category5</label>
    </span>
```

I want to add attribute checked=true to radio button by index value .
suppose, I passed index=2 then it should be selected Category2 .. 
or also want to get selected (checked=true) radio button index using in jquery..

How I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike select boxes, there isn't really a concept of an index in radio buttons.

However you can do something like this in jQuery:

```
$(".clsradio input:checked").index();
```

Which will get all the input boxes within your span that are checked (which as your using radio's should only be one, if only one group is inside .clsradio).

Here is an [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexkey/3SVTa/)

---

EDIT:

A more full proof example (but slower) would be:

```
$("input[name$='rdlCategory']:checked").index();
```

Which gets inputs ending in rdlCategory. You could even add ":radio" but you don't need to.

---

EDIT 2 - Checking by passing in index.

You can use:

```
 $(".clsradio input:nth-child(5)").attr("checked", "checked");
```

nth-child using the "input" selector can be used as the index.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, And I also want to set checked=true by index.. If I passed index=2 then it should checked category2

Comment: Sorry @Abhishek I don't understand "If I passed index=2 then it should checked category2" ? Do you want to be able to select them yourself in javascript?

Comment: Actually @@Abhishek don't worry I understand now - I'll update my answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: If no one is selected then I want selected by passing integer value for initial selection.. Is any way to add attribute checked=true by index...

Comment: @Abhishek-try this $('input:radio').index(0).attr('checked', true);

Comment: Thanks @Vivek  good idea, but I had a play with it and I don't think you can pass in a parameter to index() like that. I think it has to be a selector or element. http://api.jquery.com/index/ I've updated my answer to use nth-child

Comment: No worries @Vivek, though I really liked your idea. It would be great if index() could be used like that - perhaps you should suggest it to the jQuery team. @Abhishek I'm sure there are other ways, but nth-child would be a good solution.

Comment: Glad to help @Abhishek, have a nice day too.

Answer (score 1):

use [**index**](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method of jquery

```
function selectRadioButton(inputindex){
    $('input[name="ctl00$cphTop$rdlCategory"]').index(inputindex).attr('checked', true);
}
```

to get selected radio button index...

```
var selectedIndex =  $('input[name="ctl00$cphTop$rdlCategory"]').attr('checked', true).index(inputindex);
```

Comment: radio button not generats list it generates sequences of <input> and label in flow layout.

Comment: Hello @vivek..  How to passed name instead of (ctl00$cphTop$rdlCategory) .. it becomes dynamically.. not fixed.. when viewed from page source it seen like this...

Comment: i am not asp.net developer...so i don't know about it's syntax..but simply you can pass tha variable containing name of radiobutton..

Comment: For dynamic ASP use code in my answer, the rest you can take from Vivek.

Comment: you can use `$('input:radio').attr('checked', true).index(inputindex); `

Comment: that's great...so how you are going to accept the answer...because every answer has something to pick up- :)

Comment: hello vivek It getting error index() not a function. whats going wrong..?

Comment: have you given the refrence of jquery api?

Comment: how it can be possible then..which veersion of jquery you are using

Comment: include this in your page head http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Hello @Vivek It is not possible to change my old version script to newer.. because in my application I used 1.3.2 so if I change to newers then it conflits my other javascript so.. now it will not possible...

Answer (score 1):

```
    $("#<%= rdlCategory.ClientID %> input:checked").index();
```

As for how select items in ASP.NET using jQuery, i'm not sure it will work in all scenarios. ASP.NET updates ViewState each time you touch ASP.NET control thus i wouldn't use much jQuery to manipulate values of selection

if you still want this then `$(selector).attr("checked",true);`

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
$($("input[name='GroupName']").get(index)).prop('checked', true);
```

Explanation:

`$("input[name='GroupName']")` returns a list of items that have the name 'GroupName'

`.get(index)` returns the `i`th item in the list. In the case of a radio group this would be the input tag you want.

The input tag is an HTML element, not a jQuery item, so you re-wrap it. Then you can call the `prop` method.

```
$(html).prop('checked',true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unchecked will give "undefined" otherwise it will return the value of the selected object.

```
$('input[name=ctl00$cphTop$rdlCategory]:checked').val()
```