# jQuery checked radio button index always return zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I have the following radio buttons in a page has bootstrap and [jquery-ui](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui) :

```
<input type="radio" name="activeSolution" value="48">
...
<input type="radio" name="activeSolution" value="50">
...
<input type="radio" name="activeSolution" value="10">
```

I'm trying to get the checked radio button index in from jQuery autocomplete select event as the following:

```
....
select: function( event, ui ) {           
       active = $("input:radio[name='activeSolution']:checked").index();
       alert($("input[name='activeSolution']:checked").index());
       alert(active)
....
```

Always `alert(active)` returns `0` What I have did is almost like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492046/how-to-get-or-set-selected-index-of-the-radio-button-list-using-jquery).

I also tried to supply the element to the `index()` like the following:

```
active = $("input:radio[name='activeSolution']");
   alert(active.index(active.find(":checked")));
```

However, this returns `-1`

**Edit**: adding the full code context of jQuery ui:

```
<script>
$( function() {    

    $( "#solutions" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
          console.log(request.term)
        $.ajax( {
          url: "/solution/autocomplete/"+request.term,
          dataType: "json",
         /* data: {
            term: request.term
          },*/
          success: function( data ) {
            response( data );
          }
        } );
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
       /* log( "Selected: " + ui.item.label + " aka " + ui.item.value );*/

       active = $("input:radio[name='activeSolution']:checked").index();
       alert($("input[name='activeSolution']:checked").index());
       alert(active)

       //alert($("input.activeSolution:checked").index());
      /* active = $("input:radio[name='activeSolution']");
       alert(active.index(active.find(":checked")));
       alert(active)
       alert(active.index(active.find(':checked')))*/
        this.value = ui.item.label;
        console.log(this)
        li = '<li class="list-group-item">'+ui.item.label+'<input type="hidden" name="solutions[][]" value="'+ui.item.value+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger badge remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button></li>';
        notFound = true;
        $(".solutions-list li input[name='solutions["+this.title+"][]']").each(function(i){
            //alert($(this).val()+"\n"+ui.item.value)
            if ($(this).val() == ui.item.value){
                alert('{{__('This cause is already selected!')}}');
                notFound = false;
                return false;
            }

        });
        if (notFound) $("#solutions-list").prepend(li);
        return false;
      }
    } );
  } );
  </script>
```

Comment: I suspect you are expecting to get indexes like 0,1,2? If so I did a few changes to your code in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zmudg91v/ but I don't know if this change can be applied to your proyect.

Comment: @Lixus In my code context, jquery ui autocomplete, it does not work. always returns 0.

Comment: @SaidbakR Can you show us any example of jsfiddle or snippet, please

Comment: [`index` with no arguments returns the index of the DOM element relative to its siblings](https://api.jquery.com/index/). It looks like you have more HTML nodes than just radio buttons, so might want to look into the single-argument use eg. `$("input:radio[name='activeSolution']").index(":checked")`. It's a bit unclear what the expected behaviour is, could you make a [mcve]?

Comment: @blgt Yes I have other nodes, however, in `active.length` in my code returns correct length i.e correct regarded radio buttons count on my page. However, the only working soly=tion that I have found yet, is to loop through the radio buttons using `active.each(...` and checking for the checked property for each element.